# Hide Facebook fan page videos tab from not fans

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

I would like to add videos to my Facebook fan page but I want to allow fans only to watch them. I searched online and I found lots of information about how to hide content from non fans but none about hiding the videos tab.
Also, all the stuff I saw used FBML which is now obsolete and will disappear on June 1st.

Can anyone please help ? I would really appreciate it
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would check out this [article](http://www.daddydesign.com/wordpress/how-to-use-a-fan-gate-on-your-iframe-tab-to-hide-content-until-someone-likes-your-facebook-fan-page/). It tells you how to use CSS to hide certain content from users who are not fans of your page.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Zack but all the tutorials I found including this one is about a custom tab. I want to hide the videos application tab from non fans. Do you have any idea if it's even possible ?

Comment: Couldn't you just make the your page's wall non visible to non fans? This would be the easy way to solve your problem. To my knowledge, I don't think you can single out just videos from users, unless there is an option provided by facebook.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to actually hide the application from non-fans. Your best bet is to get a custom tab and then embed the video's in that tab as fan only content. Then move the video's application out of view on your timeline. When you hover over and app you will see a little pencil appear, and it will say swap with another application. If you have enough applications on your page you can move the video application in the app overflow area. If your like me I swapped out all my facebook apps so I only show my custom apps which give me the control to show and hide content from non-fans. check out http://Tabbed.co they do this full time. See and example at http://fb.com/tabbedco